# Unable to Import data into SQL Server 2022

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2022

I just downloaded SQL Server 2022. I tried importing data into it, but cannot access the import/export data option as they both appear offline.

This error was displayed:

> This feature is unavailable in this version or the database does not exist

I right clicked on task, expecting to Import data but Import data appeared offline

Comment: What version exactly? I don't think Express version includes SSIS. Regardless there are may ways to import data that don't require this feature

Comment: Version 16.0.1000.6

What other alternative can I use in importing data please @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Log into SSMS, connect to a database and type `SELECT @@VERSION` that will tell you if you have express or not. What format is the data you want to import? is it txt or csv? Please try and include all information